# Vite don't transpile code with Babel plugin

Tags: javascript, babeljs, vite, babel-preset-env

I'm trying to convert default Vite template JS with Babel/preset-env, to be compatible with older browsers - to es2015. In code generated by Vite still appear const instead of var.

I'm using this plugin - https://github.com/owlsdepartment/vite-plugin-babel

My config file looks like the following:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import babel from "vite-plugin-babel";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        babel({
            babelConfig: {
                babelrc: false,
                configFile: false,
                presets: ["@babel/env"]
            },
        }),
    ],
    server: {
        host: "127.0.0.1", // I couldn't load site with localhost
    }
});
```

I can see, that on calling `npm run build` plugins declared above are loaded. I then get only 2 files inside dist folder instead of 4, which were generated when i didn't use any configuration.

I've tried to achieve this installing the following packages:

•`npm create vite@latest` - with VanillaJS

•`npm install -D vite-plugin-babel`

•`npm install -D @babel/preset-env`

I've also installed `@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping`, and tried to add this as plugin - but so far as I know, I shouldn't need it if preset-env is used, but i'm still getting `const` instead of `var` in transpiled version.

I've also tried to set vite option `build.target` to `es2015`, but it also didn't help.

I've tried to transpile Javascript into ~ES2015/ES5 integrated with Vite

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I am currently having the same issue with Vite + Ionic 7